# Xcode 4 - Adding and associating an object to an entity using relationships

Tags: core-data, xcode4

I've been learning how to use Core Data in xcode for a couple of weeks now but have been stumped on how to get the relationships to work.

In my code I have 2 entities. The "House" entity and the "City" entity. A house can only belong in 1 city, but a city can have many houses associated with it. So I set up a one-to-many relationship between the house and city entities.

The following code snippet is in the city view controller, which is just a table view that displays all available cities to choose from. The list is pre-populated in the city entity. Now when I select a row I try to execute the following code to associate a house with the selected city but the result is always nil.

The referringObject is the house object that I am creating
cities is the relationship from the house to the city entity

Any help is appreciated

```
NSManagedObject *selectedCity =
    [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[self.referringObject setValue:[selectedCity valueForKey:@"cityname"] 
    forKeyPath:@"cities.cityname"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to associate the city object with the house object.  You don't need to change the cityname value inside of it.  That way you only have one entry in the table for each city.  So what you want to do is:

```
 NSManagedObject *selectedCity = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
[self.referringObject setValue:selectedCity forKeyPath:@"city"];
```

That'll set up your both relationships for you.  You can then access the city's name from a house object with houseObj.city.cityname or get the list of houses in a city with city.houses (assuming you named the relationship houses).

Comment: One addition, to get the dot notation use you need to set-up NSManagedObject subclasses with properties to do that.  Otherwise you need to go through the -value:forKey: methods.  I'm so used to automatically doing that that I wasn't thinking about it not being standard.  I'd recommend getting mogenerator to do it for you.

Comment: Why are you guys manipulating NSManagedObjects? The whole idea of ORM frameworks is to deal with the objects?

Comment: The biggest reason I create the NSManagedObject subclasses to to add the @dynamic properties to it.  [object setSomeProperty:value]; is much cleaner to me than [object setValue:value forKey:@"someProperty"]; to me and is less error prone since the compiler doesn't verify your key strings are valid.  The other main reason I usually do it is for transient values.  Like if you need to store a color, you have to store an archive of it.  So you have the methods that pack and unpack it for you.